# Output Mismatch in ctypes and C++

Tags: ctypes

I have a dll with a custom type variable that is populated after passing by ref into getstatus function.

C++:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct Status_ {
    unsigned char mode;
    unsigned char state;                        
    unsigned int info;                       
    unsigned int errorCode;                     
    unsigned char selected;                 
    char id[25];                            
}Status;
#pragma pack(pop)

Status status = { 0 };
int ret = GetStatus(someid, &status)
```

Python:

```
class Status(Structure):
 _fields_ = [("mode", c_ubyte),      
("state", c_ubyte),                  
("info", c_uint),
("errorCode", c_uint),
("selected", c_ubyte),               
("id", c_char * 25)]   

status = Status()
getStatus = dll.GetStatus
getStatus.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(Status)]
getStatus.restype = c_int
ret = getStatus(someid, byref(status));
```

I'm not sure what is wrong but I'm getting different values for the status fields in C++ and python.

EDIT: added missing pragma preprocessor from dll code

Comment: Please add additional info to prove your claim. And also some working code. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Everything looks good but the fields as shown would have padding so it is probably a packing issue. As a guess, add `_pack_ = 1` to the structure.

Comment: Look for a `#pragma pack` or equivalent in the original header

Comment: @MarkTolonen There's a #pragma pack(push, 1) in the header. How do I define this in the ctypes stucture?

Comment: adding the _pack_ to ctypes structures fixed it. Thanks a lot. If you can post it as an answer. That'll be great @MarkTolonen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set the packing if indicated in the header; otherwise, extra padding bytes are added between fields that don’t align to natural address boundaries. For example, the 4-byte “info” parameter normally would have two bytes of padding added before it so its offset in the structure would be a multiple of 4.

Add `_pack_ = 1` to remove all packing bytes.

```py
class Status(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (("mode", c_ubyte),      
                ("state", c_ubyte),                  
                ("info", c_uint),
                ("errorCode", c_uint),
                ("selected", c_ubyte),               
                ("id", c_char * 25))   

status = Status()
getStatus = dll.GetStatus
getStatus.argtypes = c_int, POINTER(Status)
getStatus.restype = c_int
ret = getStatus(someid, byref(status))
```